# Existence of a certain oscillating power series?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Is there a power series with complex coefficients and is convergent around $0$ with radius $1$, but is unbounded on segment $[0,1)$, and there $\exists$ $\lbrace a_n\rbrace$, $a_n \in [0,1)$, $a_n$$\rightarrow 1$, the value of the power series on $a_n$ tends to $0$?

Comment: Maybe the power series for ${1\over1-z}\sin{1\over1-z}$?

Comment: What do you mean by "value of power series on $a_n$"?

Comment: Why do you call this oscillating?

Comment: @Maesumi, let the power series be $p(z)$. Then I take it that OP is referring to $p(a_n)$.

Comment: @julien, if it's unbounded on $[0,1)$, but goes to zero for some sequence of values in $[0,1)$ tending to $1$, then its modulus has to do some furious oscillating on $[0,1)$. I assume that's what OP has in mind.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks. But the square of the same function has the same property. And yet it is nonnegative, so it does not really oscillate, no? FOr me, oscillate means that the sign keeps changing.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ok, I've looked in the dictionary and I'm wrong. You don't have to oscillate around $0$, it can be around any central value. My english has just made some progress.